# Firebase Cloud Messaging works from localhost but not on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, github-pages

**Edit: This is definitely a Github Pages issue. I deployed to Firebase Hosting and everything works as it should.

Here's my js to get the token. It is fully functional when running from localhost.

```
 const messaging = firebase.messaging();
 messaging.requestPermission()
     .then(function () {
         console.log('have permission');
         return messaging.getToken();
         console.log(messaging.getToken());
     })
     .then(function (token) {
         newToken = token
         console.log(newToken);
     })
     .catch(function (err) {
         console.log(err);
     })

 messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
     console.log('onMessage: ', payload)
 })
```

Here's is what is in my firebase-messaging-sw.js file:

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-app.js")
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-messaging.js")

var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    const title = 'hello world';
    const options = {
        body: payload.data.status
    }

    return self.registration.showNotification(title, options)
})
```

I get the following error when I try to use it from Github Pages:

> Failed to register/update a ServiceWorker for scope
>   ‘https://adambeck7.github.io/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope’:
>   Load failed with status 404 for script
>   ‘https://adambeck7.github.io/firebase-messaging-sw.js’

Comment: I think part of the problem is that the firebase-messaging-sw.js doesn't have the repo name in in the path. If I navigate here https://adambeck7.github.io/firebase-messaging-sw.js I get a 404 error but if I navigate to https://adambeck7.github.io/repo-name/firebase-messaging-sw.js it pulls up my file.